# AWS CodePipeline deploy process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I am building a CI pipeline with AWS CodePipeline.  I'm using CodeBuild to fetch my code from a repo, build a docker image and push the image to ECR. The source for my CodePipeline is my ECR repo and is triggered when an image is updated.

Now, here’s the functionality I am looking for. When a new image is pushed to ECR, I want to create an EC2 instance and then deploy the new image to that instance.  When the app in the image has completed  its task, I.e done something and pushed the results to S3, I want to terminate the instance.  It could take hours to days before the task is complete.

Is CodeDeploy the right tool to use to deploy the ECR image to an EC2 instance for this use case?  I see from the docs that CodeDeploy requires an already running instance to deploy to.  I need to create one on the fly before CodeDeploy is initiated.  Should I add a step in the CodePipeline to trigger a lambda that creates an instance before CodeDeploy gets run?

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: `It could take hours to days before the task is complete.` 
i think creating a lambda for that and when task finish ec2 instance call lambda to terminate itself

Comment: Do you think CodeDeploy is the right tool for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

CloudTrail supports logging a PutImage event that you can use to do stuff with your pipeline. I prefer producing artifacts after specific steps in your build pipeline and then have a lambda function that reacts to an `object created` event. Your lambda function could then make the necessary calls to spin up ec2 instances. Your instance could then run a job and then call lambda again, which could tear it down. It sounds like you need an on-demand worker. Services like AWS Batch or ECS might be able to provide you with this functionality out of the box.